# Automapper global destination instantiator

Tags: c#, automapper

I am using automapper to map my DTOs to Viewmodels, some of my viewmodels have a dependency to a service.

I found a couple of ways to construct the destination object using these dependencies but i wonder if it is possible to just use a global object resolver (UnityContainer in my case)?

my current solution is this:

```
config.CreateMap<SurveyDTO, SurveyViewModel>()
                .ConstructUsing(x => _ObjectResovler.Resolve<SurveyViewModel>())
```

or alternatively

```
config.CreateMap<SurveyDTO, SurveyViewModel>()
                .ConstructUsingServiceLocator()
```

But this means that i have to include a line like this in every mapping.
Is there a way to just use the resolver for all mappings without specifying it in the configuration?

Comment: DANGER WILL ROBINSON IMPROPER USE OF IOC DETECTED, DANGER DANGER.  

All kidding aside your view models should never have a service dependency and if they did using a Service Locator would be an incorrect use of IOC. 

Take some time and read a bit more about how to setup MVC applications and how to use IOC to manage them as you have gotten lost in the weeds.

Comment: @P.Roe thank you for the quick answer :), do you have a small example or something like that? I do not understand how to relay the "save" request from the viewmodel to a service without injecting the service. Currently i bind a SaveCommand to the save button. And then i'm stuck in the viewmodel. I found this structure in the xamarin CRM example (https://github.com/xamarin/app-crm/blob/master/src/MobileApp/XamarinCRM/ViewModels/Products/ProductsViewModel.cs). I found some other SO question about this but most of them end up with the viewmodel using the servicelayer.

Comment: Ahhhh, I see you're using MVVM not MVC as I assumed. That changes things considerably.  

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991965.aspx

Comment: Great article, according to figure 3 & 10 i'd say that i'm doing it the right way. But that brings me back to my original question, do i really need to tell automapper that it is allowed to use the servicelocator for every mapping ( / create the destination object manually ). It's not that much work, but it's another line that could be forgotten :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved it by using

```
config.ForAllMaps((map, opts) => opts
          .ConstructUsing(x => _ObjectResovler.Resolve(map.DestinationType)));
```

for the servicelocator alternative you could use:

```
config.ForAllMaps((map, opts) => opts.ConstructUsingServiceLocator());
```